# Problems with Submenu after resizing Jquery for responsive site (jsfiddle provided)

Tags: jquery, submenu

I have a problem with a submenu that I have created using both Jquery and CSS.

I have created the following fiddle in order to show you what's wrong with this: https://jsfiddle.net/kurt111078/c5xhLrho/8/

- 1st step: After the page is loaded, the submenu behaves correctly: when passing the mouse over the menu with submenu, the submenu is shown. Once you move the mouse out, the submenu disappears. Until here everything looks like correct.
- 2nd step: When I resize the page to see how this behaves in smaller screens, also in this case everything works fine.

The problem arises when I resize again the screen to a larger one.

I was expecting the menu to behave like in step 1 but even if the screen is larger, the submenu is now shown only if I click on the menu with submenu, which is an incorrect behavior because with larger screens the the submenu needs to be shown when I pass the mouse over the parent menu.

Could you please help me understand what's wrong with my code?

Really strange since I have already added a resize handler:

```
        $(window).resize(resizeMenu);
     resizeMenu();
    setupMenuButton();
    setupSubMenu();
});
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Following two instructions are referencing the same element and clashing the display css with each other.

```
CSS
.mynavbar li:hover > ul { display: block;}

JavaScript
function setupSubMenu() { $(".mysubmenu").toggle(); }
```

**[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/c5xhLrho/9/)**

So basically in your scenario if you want mouse hover effect on larger screen and click feature on smaller screens, you can achieve in this way:

```
function resizeMenu() {
    if ($(this).width() >= 500) {
        //.....
        //.....
        $(".munuwithsubmenu").hover(
           function(){ $(".mysubmenu").css({'display': 'block'}) },
           function(){ $(".mysubmenu").css({'display': 'none'}) }
         );
    }
    else if ($(this).width() < 500) {
        //.....
        //.....
       $(".munuwithsubmenu").off( "mouseenter mouseleave" );
    }
}
```

The trick is bind/unbind the mouseenter-mouseleave [events](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works pefectly but I cannot vote since my reputation is under 15.

Comment: No problem but I think you ( @Kurt ) can accept the answer as it was asked by you.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work